# "Enable Macros" prompt does not appear for .xla files added to user Add-Ins folder

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

My workplace has Excel's Trust Center settings for Macros locked to "Disable all macros with notification." This is usually fine as most of the macros we use are stored in the workbooks themselves, so all the user has to do is enable the macros once the document is opened.

However, we recently were given a useful add-in (.xla) that we're expected to start implementing.

However, the "Enable Macros" prompt only appears if the .xla file is opened manually. If the file is added to Excel as an actual Add-In (either through Excel's options, or by copying the file to the user's ...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns folder), the prompt does not appear.

Instead, if the user attempts to run the macro through the included keyboard shortcut, a prompt appears simply telling us that macros have been disabled for this workbook, and that it needs to be reopened.

Unfortunately the trust center settings are non-negotiable; these settings are managed site-wide and my issue is specific to my particular office.

I've attempted to run the add-in macros manually through the developer tab, but get the same result. I've also tried saving the add-in as the newer .xlam versus .xla, but again got the same result.

Is there any way to convince or trick excel into prompting the user to enable macros when using an add-in? Or are the users stuck with needing to open the file manually each day?

Comment: Although you can't add a trusted location, do you have any existing trusted locations as Excel exists now on your PCs? There must be at least one (the personal add-in library) otherwise add-ins wouldn't work.  You could always have a batch file to copy them from a network share to a location on your PCs which is trusted.

Comment: Negative, all trusted locations are disabled. Add-ins do work if they are opened manually (i.e. from windows explorer), and the user clicks "Enable Macros" on the prompt that appears.

Comment: So you cant use one of the Excel ones like solver or Analysis Toolpack?

Comment: Never thought of testing those before, but after testing it seems they do work with a prompt (a different one than usual though, asking if the user wants to enable add-ins). Perhaps it has something to do with the startup/initialization code of the original problematic .xla?

Comment: Try and create a really simple addin and put in the same folder as the Microsoft ones?